# How can to make a new user see table in existing schema

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, permissions, schema, users

I'm new into Oracle so this question might be dumb. I created new user and now I would like him to see table (or even better all tables by one command) in already existing schema (hr schema in this case). Is it even possible?

From my understanding databases store data and Schemas are equal to Users, so can two users see the same data stored in database, like in my case?

Answer (score 1):

Log in as HR user and run following statement (first replacing the OTHER_USER with actual username):

```
select 'GRANT SELECT ON ' || table_name || ' TO OTHER_USER;' from user_tables;
```

then copy the output, paste and execute it as HR user.

Comment: Is there some sqlplus command equivalent to this statement?

Answer (score 1):

It is something Oracle could have solved ages ago. There is no simple command do it, so usually we just loop through the tables and grant object level privileges:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  l_cmd clob;
begin
  for t in (select * from all_tables where owner = 'HR')
  loop
    begin
      l_cmd := 'grant select on "' || t.owner || '"."' || t.table_name || '" to new_user';
      execute immediate l_cmd;
      exception when others then dbms_output.put_line(l_cmd);
    end;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Tables created after this in HR schema will not be visible to the other user, each time an object is created, the privileges should be granted on that.

A better solution is to create a role, lets say `HR_READONLY`, and each time a new table is created in HR schema, the privileges on that object should be granted to `HR_READONLY`. Then you can just simply grant this role to the other user. This requires some self discipline from the developers, but I have seen some of them follow this method.

Comment: Is there some sqlplus command equivalent to this statement?
When I log as hr user and try this command it's not working: grant select on jobs to TestUser;

Comment: @Rocket128 - no.  But the `Database Idea` is `Under Review - Voting still open`.  See:  https://community.oracle.com/ideas/2333  (requires registration to Vote)

Comment: Why would you need a sqlplus command "equivielnt to" a simple SQL statement? Unfortunately "it's not working" contains no actionable information, but my guess is you did not enter the command exactly as @Michael gave it. Show us with copy and paste exactly what you entered and what you got.  And what he left out is that you need to spool the output to a file.  I leave it as an exercise for the  student to research use of the sqlplus "spool" command.

Comment: It's not that @Michael's statement didn't work for me, I was just curious if there is any equivalent

Comment: @Rocket128 - but you specifically said "it's not working".

Comment: @EdStevens you got me wrong. The command I put along with that comment wasn't working, this one specific: "grant select on jobs to TestUser;". But i was my fault because this command works find, which I found out later. (I was Selecting on another user from Jobs, not from hr.Jobs). My bad, once again. Sorry